# JAX vs NumPy array indexing - out of bounds behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, jax

Given the following Python code using NumPy (np) and JAX's jax.numpy module (jnp)

```
import numpy as np
import jax.numpy as jnp

x_np = np.arange(10)
x_jnp = jnp.arange(10)

### NumPy
try: # prints: You cannot do this in NumPy
    print(x_np[13]) # indexing single index
except IndexError:
    print("You cannot do this in NumPy")
try: # prints: []
    print(x_np[13:15]) # indexing range of indices
except IndexError:
    print("You cannot do this in NumPy")

# JAX
try: # prints: 9
    print(x_jnp[13]) # indexing single index
except IndexError:
    print("You cannot do this in JAX")
try: # prints: []
    print(x_jnp[13:15]) # indexing range of indices
except IndexError:
    print("You cannot do this in JAX")
```

I wonder what is the reason for JAX behaving in the above way (returning 9 for upper out of bounds and 0 for lower out of bounds when indexing for single index. returning empty arrays when indexing for a range of indices) and not throwing an "IndexError: index out of bounds" error as we would receive in NumPy?

Comment: `x_np[13:15]` doesn't throw an error in numpy either

Comment: That's right, see my comment (# prints: []) above in the code, it an empty array.

Comment: `x_jnp[13:15]` behavior follows a precedent set by Python for lists and strings.

Comment: @hpaulj that's right, in fact it is consistent for lists, strings, JAX arrays, NumPy arrays, Torch tensors etc.

Answer (score 2):

JAX's departure from NumPy's behavior when it comes to out-of-bound indexing is intended, and is discussed here: [JAX Sharp Bits: Out-of-Bounds Indexing](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#out-of-bounds-indexing).

In brief, the issue is that JAX is designed for execution on accelerators like GPU and TPU, which don't generally have APIs to surface runtime errors to the host.

If you use the [`jnp.ndarray.at`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.ndarray.at.html) property, it gives you some tools to control the behavior of out-of-bound indices; for example:

```py
>>> import jax.numpy as jnp
>>> x_jnp = jnp.arange(10.0)
>>> x_jnp.at[13].get()
Array(9., dtype=float32)
>>> x_jnp.at[13].get(mode='fill', fill_value=jnp.nan)
Array(nan, dtype=float32)
```

Note also that the experimental [`checkify`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.experimental.checkify.checkify.html) transform does provide the ability to do runtime checks for out-of-bound indices:

```py
from jax.experimental.checkify import checkify, index_checks
from functools import partial

@partial(checkify, errors=index_checks)
def getval(x, i):
  return x[i]

err, output = getval(x_jnp, 13)
err.throw()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OOBError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
OOBError: out-of-bounds indexing for array of shape (10,): index 13 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10. Failed at <ipython-input-13-4be8b1ab065a>:6 (getval)
```

This functionality may be rolled into the core jax index operations at some point in the future.